# collectstatic throws 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:' on dotcloud

Tags: django, dotcloud

As instructed in the dotcloud tutorial, this is the code in my `postinstall`:

```
#!/bin/sh  
python createdb.py  
python some_project/manage.py syncdb --noinput
python mkadmin.py
mkdir -p /home/dotcloud/data/media /home/dotcloud/volatile/static
ln -sf /home/dotcloud/volatile/static /home/dotcloud/static
python some_project/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

...`nginx.conf`

```
location /media/ { root /home/dotcloud/data ; }
```

...and `settings.py`

```
....
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/dotcloud/data/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/dotcloud/volatile/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

....

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'some_project',
)
```

When `postinstall` is run, this error is thrown:
`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/dotcloud/rsync-1346498181296/some_project/static'`

I've been on it for a long time and its confusing because the documentation says `/static/` is already setup by the python service and links to `/home/dotcloud/static`

Can someone assist? Everything worked well until I got to setting up the app for static content. Django version is 1.4.1 on Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting some sleep, I discovered that my 'static' folder was not in the location I specified in my 'settings.py' file.

Also, dotCloud has updated their documentation to warn that '/static/' is no longer automatically created as earlier stated so I changed my `postinstall` script to remove the symlink to '/static/' and also adjusted the `nginx.conf` file as instructed in the updated documentation.

Reference:
[Handlinng static files on dotCloud](http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/tutorials/python/django/#handle-static-and-media-assets)

Comment: Hi, I'm a django+dotcom newbie trying to set up static based on the newest documentation: http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/tutorials/python/django/#handle-static-and-media-assets. I'm also getting 

22:33:43.553537: [www.0] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/dotcloud/rsync-1360362707945/static'

Any changes needs to be done to the configuration given in this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Any error messages like "./postinstall failed with return code" means that there is a problem with your own script, not the platform.

In order to debug postinstall executions easily on dotCloud, you can do the following:

Let's assume that your app is "ramen" and your service is "www".

```
$ dotcloud -A ramen run www
> ~/current/postinstall
```

It'll re-execute the postinstall but from your session this time, so you'll be able to easily update the postinstall code and re-run it without having to push again and again.

Once you found the root cause, fix it locally and repush your application.